# Pandas : Getting unique rows for a given column but conditional on some criteria of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 2.7.  From a given data as follows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':['001','001','001','002','002','003','003','003','004','005'],
                   'status':['ground','unknown','air','ground','unknown','ground','unknown','unknown','unknown','ground'],
                   'value':[10,-5,12,20,-12,2,-4,-1,0,6]})
```

The data looks like this:

```
id     status     value
001    ground       10
001    unknown      -5
001    air          12
002    ground       20
002    unknown     -12
003    ground        2
003    unknown      -4
003    unknown      -1
004    unknown       0
005    ground        6
```

I would like to get the output in dataframe that has unique id conditional to the following criteria: For a given id

```
 'status': If 'air' does exist, pick 'air'.
           If 'air' does not exist, pick 'ground'.  
           If both 'air' and 'ground' do not exist, pick 'unknown'.

 'value': Sum of values for each id
 'count': Count the number of rows for each id
```

Therefore, the expected output is the following.

```
id     status     value     count
001     air        17        3
002    ground       8        2
003    ground      -3        3
004    unknown      0        1
005    ground       6        1
```

I can do looping for each unique id but it is not elegant enough and computation is also expensive, especially when data becomes large.  May i know the better pythonic style and more efficient way to come up with this output?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `groupby` on id. This is easy for value and count but trickier for the status. We need to write our own function which takes a pandas Series and returns a single attribute.

```
def group_status(x):
    if (x=='air').any():
        y = 'air'
    elif (x=='ground').any():
        y = 'ground'
    else:
        y = 'unknown'
    return y

data = data.groupby(by='id').agg({'value': ['sum', 'count'], 'status': [group_status]})
data.columns = ['status', 'value', 'count']

print(data)

     status  value  count
id          
001  air      17     3
002  ground   8      2
003  ground   -3     3
004  unknown  0      1
005  ground   6      1
```

Here we have ensured that the air, ground, unknown order is preserved without the need to change the column type to categorical, as mentioned in ayhan's very elegant answer.

The `group_status()` function does lay the groundwork should you wish to incorporate more advanced groupby functionality.

Comment: Categorical columns are not sorted alphabetically but in the order they are passed to `.astype`. So if you change it to ['ground', 'air', 'unknown'], ground will be the first value if it exists.

Comment: I didn't know that. It is certainly useful to know. I read as "as your example is ordered" and overlooked the first line of code. I shall edit my answer slighty.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be changing the type of status column to category and sorting based on that in groupby.agg:

```
df['status'] = df['status'].astype('category', categories=['air', 'ground', 'unknown'], ordered=True)

df.sort_values('status').groupby('id').agg({'status': 'first', 'value': ['sum', 'count']})
Out: 
      status value      
       first   sum count
id                      
001      air    17     3
002   ground     8     2
003   ground    -3     3
004  unknown     0     1
005   ground     6     1
```

Here, since the values are sorted in `'air'`, `'ground'` and `'unknown'` order, `'first'` returns the correct value. If you don't want to change the type, you can define your own function that returns `air`/`ground`/`unknown` and instead of `'first'` you can pass that function.